# Serverless Framework Api Gateway TypeError

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a serverless template which includes a lambda function with API gateway. I've included an api key to the template. Everything deploys fine, BUT I still receive the following type error at the end:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'apiKeys' of undefined`

I can't really find any good solution to this problem. Here is a sample of my serverless template where I include the apikeys:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-add-api-key
provider:
  name: aws
  timeout: 30 # Because API Gateway
  runtime: python3.8
  region: us-east-1
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - MyKey
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are mixing up the ways in which we configure api keys with and without the [serverless-add-api-key](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-add-api-key) plugin. Following is a working serverless.yml without using the plugin.

```
service: serverless-api-key

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: prod
  timeout: 30
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  apiGateway:
    apiKeys:
      - MyKey
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: get
```

sls deploy output below -

```
Service Information
service: serverless-api-key
stage: prod
region: ap-south-1
stack: serverless-api-key-prod
resources: 14
api keys:
  MyKey: Aeeblv4djg2AmlXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2fk9l4iCDRf
endpoints:
  GET - https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/hello
functions:
  hello: serverless-api-key-prod-hello
layers:
  None
```

If you still want to use the plugin, you need to get the correct syntax. You can use the below serverless.yml -

```
service: serverless-api-key-2

plugins:
  - serverless-add-api-key
custom:
  apiKeys:
    - name: MyKey33

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: prod
  region: ap-south-1
  timeout: 30
  runtime: nodejs12.x
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: get
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your assistance.